# csv to datagridview in c# windows application

Tags: c#, csv

hi everyone and thanks in advance, i have a .csv file in the given format below.
i need to display this value in datagridview of c# windows application in three column like Number Date-Time Message and every thing rest will be ignore..including doublequotes,sms,deliver please help me i am new to this please help..

sms,deliver,"+919999999999","","","2013.08.01 12:52","","AVAILABLE ON RENT 3BHK Flat 102 1Floor @Mansarovar,mount pleasant rd., Malabar Hill. West Seafacing .partial seaview as building on slope Airy Well Lit Spacious1800carpet 3bhk,store+servant rm+bathrm wid separate entrance+shutter closed garage260capet,fully furnished wid white goods for immediate lease."

sms,deliver,"+919999999999","","","2013.08.01 09:40","","Following apartment in Khar for lease: SHIKHA, Near SHATRANJ, Off Carter Road, Khar Garden facing 1500 sq.ft. 3BHK semi furnished + 1 car parking bay. Lease @ Rs. 1.25 lacs Immediate possession. 2 hours notice for inspection. --Rohit J."

sms,deliver,"+919999999999","","","2013.07.31 20:37","","direct 1bhk( Deepak silverene@55 Hill n sea@70 Vindhyachal@70 2bhk West side@80 Harmony @90 Neptune@1.6 Bldg no 22@55 3bhk Elco Residency@1.5 Firdos manzil@1.10 Radhe narayan@1.25 Vertical bliss@2.75 4bhk Vinayk heights@4lac RawthanI garden@1.75 Cl/sms"

i have tried this code..

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists("E:\\messages.csv"))
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader("E:\\messages.csv");

            //Checking the end of file's content
            if (fileReader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                string fileRow = fileReader.ReadLine();
                string[] fileDataField = fileRow.Split(',');
                int count = fileDataField.Count();

                //Adding Column Header to DataGridView
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn columnDataGridTextBox = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                    columnDataGridTextBox.Name = fileDataField[i];
                    columnDataGridTextBox.HeaderText = fileDataField[i];
                    columnDataGridTextBox.Width = 120;
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(columnDataGridTextBox);
                }

                //Adding Data to DataGridView
                while (fileReader.Peek() != -1)
                {
                    fileRow = fileReader.ReadLine();
                    fileDataField = fileRow.Split(',');
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(fileDataField);
                }
            }

            //Close the StreamReader
            fileReader.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you try something

Comment: yes but i did not get the desired output..what i have explained above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in linq like this

```
 var lines = File.ReadAllLines("yourcsvfile.csv").Select(a => a.Split(',')).ToList();

        foreach (string[] s in lines)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s[5], s[6], s[7]);
        }
```

by the way i tried your input and it seems there are 7 columns not 3. Do you want to exclude any?

Comment: yes i want to exclude 1st and 2nd then 3rd one is number i want this the the datetime i want and then the full message part i want

Comment: well you can just execute the first line and can see that you get csv list. You can ignore whatever elements you want to ignore.

Comment: can u provide me with the code that u r talking about..please.. :)

Comment: @ShaikhMohammadSufiyan i mean something like above. ofcourse you will have to do error handling as well as provide the correct column numbers in s[]

Comment: yes sir..thank you very much...this helps me lot but now i am getting error no row can be added without column..and i hope i can now solve it...thank you very much..

Comment: add your desired columns in grid view first.

Comment: thank you again..sir i have solved my problem thank you very much sir again..and happy ramazaan sir..

Comment: Glad it helped. Blessed Ramadan.